# Force format of data input by user as text

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel sheet where the user can enter data into several cells.
I want this data to be treated as strings, regardless if the user enters something as "Hello" or "123" or "12.12.2012".

I could partially resolve this issue by formatting the input cells as "Text". But now if the user enters a number such as "123" or a string that looks like a date ("12.12.2012"), it appears with a small green rectangle and Excel says that the number is stored as text, but that's exactly what I want. Same thing with the text "1.2.90" in cell A5 which is seen by Excel as "date stored as text". The text "AA" in cell A4 is OK.

When I click on the exclamation mark icon, I can choose to ignore the "error", which removes the green triangle, but as soon as I change the content of the cell by putting another number, the green triangle appears again.

[image]

*Green field are formatted as "Text"*

Is there any way to force Excel to leave the data entered as string ?

Comment: Yes. There is It is called "Switching the Error Check Off" Also voting this question to be moved to SU as it is Off topic here.

Comment: http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/excel-help/use-error-checking-to-correct-common-errors-in-formulas-HA010342331.aspx

Comment: @SiddharthRout: thank you that works.... But unfortunately this is a global Excel setting. I need the same thing but local to an Excel file. With your solution my Excel File will do what I want on **my** computer, but if I give the Excel file to someone else the triangles will appear again unless this person switches of error checking manually.

Comment: You can tun them off via code. BUt then here is a catch. The code won't run if the macros are disabled in other pc :)

Comment: That's OK. I already **have** macros in this Excel file and with macros disabled nothing will work anyway. The correcponding property is **Application.ErrorCheckingOptions.BackgroundChecking**. Thank's for the quick na dhelpful answer. Make this answer and I'll accept it. Otherwise I'll answer my own question.

Comment: Since you want to do it via VBA, I have retracted my vote. Also yes, you need to use `ErrorCheckingOptions.BackgroundChecking` to achieve what you want via VBA.

Comment: + 1 On finally finding an answer yourself just from a hint ;)

Comment: Just one more question: why did you first vote for moving the question to SU since is tagged "ecxel". IMO it's not off topic even if there was VBA involved. Or did I miss something ?

Comment: Yes it was tagged VBA which normally happens on formula questions as well. Since it was not specifically specified that you were looking for a VBA solution, it appeared to me that you were unaware of the Excel's inbuilt functionality. Usually people opt in for NON VBA Method over VBA Method. And hence I voted it to be moved to superuser.com and at the same time let you know about it so that if I was wrong then I can retract my vote which I did :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46937/discussion-between-michael-walz-and-siddharth-rout)

Comment: Well, it does the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NON VBA Version**

You can switch off the error tracking from the File Tab. To read about it, check this [MS Link](http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/excel-help/use-error-checking-to-correct-common-errors-in-formulas-HA010342331.aspx).

**VBA Version**

To do that using VBA, you need to switch off the `BackgroundChecking` using `Application.ErrorCheckingOptions.BackgroundChecking`

Example

```
Application.ErrorCheckingOptions.BackgroundChecking = False
```

You can read more about it [HERE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb220876%28v=office.12%29.aspx)